# onChange string is not equal in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

After converting a random Int number to a string, I check if the user has typed that number correctly. However, although the number I typed in the console and the number displayed on the screen are correct, the if block does not work.

When I try Turkish as a language it works correctly, but when I try German it only works correctly for numbers between 0 and 20.
for example:
3 = dreissig - True
11 = elf - True
23 = drieundzwanzig - (The if block doesn't work here.)
but when I try the number 23 in Turkish, it works correctly.

When the number 23 does not execute the if block, when I copy it from the console and paste it into the TextField, the if block works.

**I am converting a number that is an int to text:**

```
final class NumberConfig {
    static var shared = NumberConfig()
    
    private init() { }
    
    func convertNumberToString(number: Int) -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de-DE")
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        if let text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) {
            return text
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

**NumberToTextStudyView:**

```
TextField("", text: $inputNumber)
.onChange(of: inputNumber) { value in
     isNumberEqual(inputNumber: value, number: stringNumber)
  }

func isNumberEqual(inputNumber: String, number: String) {
    print("\(inputNumber) - \(number)")
    
    if number == inputNumber {
        print("equal")
    } else {
        print("not equal")
    }
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `NumberFormatter` inserts *Soft Hyphen* characters (`hex 0x00ad`) between the syllables which are **not** displayed, in case of 23 *drei-und-zwanzig*. You can prove it by un-commenting the `print` line. As UTF8 data the character is displayed `c2ad`

Just filter out the character

```
func convertNumberToString(number: Int) -> String {
    let softHyphen = "\u{00ad}"
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de-DE")
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
    if let text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) {
        // print(Data(text.utf8) as NSData)
        return text.replacingOccurrences(of: softHyphen, with: "")
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```